# cannot run roscore due to error in rosversion

Tags: ros, roscore, rosversion, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running roscore with a new groovy install, i get this error:

```
... logging to /u/bhaskara/.ros/log/2674d9d4-0ccb-11e2-9426-f46d0429e87d/roslaunch-spf-11815.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/u/bhaskara/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.
WARNING: disk usage in log directory [/u/bhaskara/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
It's recommended that you use the 'rosclean' command.
2;roscore
Cannot locate [ros]Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44996/cannot-run-roscore-due-to-error-in-rosversion/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is caused by having a previously-installed "pip" version of rospkg which is out of date.

Fix this by:

sudo pip uninstall rospkg

*repeat this until it says "not found"*

then to be sure you have the latest:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-rospkg

The "pip uninstall" version is supposed to work, but personally I did:

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ros*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/catkin*

to remove the old pip-installed versions.  This should be safe for both Fuerte and Groovy users, because these tools are all now installed to /usr/ instead of /usr/local and are available as debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-04**:
Thanks this really helped me out.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2014-12-18**:
Worked for me as well for Indigo, I had an old Fuerte installed. But I didn't had to do the last steps with sudo rm.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Actually, rospkg should not be installed using easy_install or pip anymore."

How have you installed rosdep/rospkg?

See my answer on that possible duplicate question and the link in Lorenz' comment: [problem-to-start-roscore-on-arm-ubuntu-1204/?answer=42334](http://answers.ros.org/question/42321/problem-to-start-roscore-on-arm-ubuntu-1204/?answer=42334#post-id-42334)

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2